# Why I can't reproduce this Windows bug?

Tags: windows-xp, notepad

We all know about the famous **bush hid the facts** bug of Microsoft.

By searching on the internet, I found out that any word sequence of sizes 4-3-3-5 separated by spaces, saved as .txt file and opened by Notepad, would create the bug.

eg:

- aaaa aaa aaa aaaa
- part two and three
- girl are you crazy
- jatd lue ywq mas

etc.

But, when I try to write my name, ie, **Priydarshi Singh** in the form of `priy dar shi singh`, and save it as a .txt file, it comes out as it is.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts), the bug was fixed from Vista onwards.

> The bug appeared for the first time in Windows NT 3.5, released 1994, but was not discovered until early 2004.[3] Older versions of Notepad such as those that came with Windows 95, 98, ME, and NT 3.1 do not include Unicode support, so the bug does not occur there.
>
> The bug exists in all successive versions of Windows until and
>   including Windows XP, but was not present in Windows Vista and
>   afterwards.

From the same article:

> While "Bush hid the facts" is the sentence most commonly presented on
>   the Internet to induce the error, the bug can be triggered by many
>   sentences with characters and spaces in a particular order so that the
>   bytes match the UTF-16LE encoding of valid (if nonsensical) Chinese
>   Unicode characters. Other popular strings are "this app can break",
>   "acre vai pra globo" (Portuguese for "Acre goes to Rede Globo"), and
>   "aaaa aaa aaa aaaaa".[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts) The bug is triggered even by the text "a ".
>
> The bug occurs when the string is passed to the Win32 charset
>   detection function IsTextUnicode with no other characters.
>   IsTextUnicode sees what it thinks is valid UTF-16LE Chinese and
>   returns true, and the application then incorrectly interprets the text
>   as UTF-16LE.[2]

So not all combinations of 4-3-3-5 will trigger the bug.

Comment: Is there any way to know which sequence will trigger the bug and which won't?